# how to check the api call is finished from a different method in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I have an onChange text handler which call the api when ever the text field value changes.

```
 const onChangeHandler = (): Promise<void> => {
    //payload value
        return apiCall(payload)(dispatch).then((res) => {
            if(response) {
               
            }    
        })
    }
```

Similarly i have a submit button which call when the user clicks the button. is there anyway to wait for the onChange api calls to finish and then call the save method?

```
 const onSave = (): Promise<void> => {
    //wait for onchange api to complete and trigger save api call.
        return apiSaveCall(payload)(dispatch).then((res) => {
            if(response) {
               
            }    
        })
    }
```

I have tried to implement promises but since both api calls are happening in different methods i had to call again the onChange method get the Promise.

A help would be really appreciable .

Comment: Whats with `return new Promise((resolve) => resolve());` that achieves nothing.  And your braces are unbalanced. Looks like made up code rather than something that actually runs

Comment: @JaromandaX yes modified the code. i just need an idea to me implimented.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the onChangeHandler use state to set it to loading

   ```
      const onChangeHandler = (): Promise<void> => {
            //payload value
         this.setState({isLoading: true})
           return apiCall(payload)(dispatch).then((res) => {
            if(response) {
               this.setState({isLoading: false})
            }    
          })
      }
   ```
2. In the save: check if it is still loading or has already loaded

   ```
    const onSave = (): Promise<void> => {
        if(this.state.isLoading){
          alert("Wait") return
        }
         //wait for onchange api to complete and trigger save api call.
        return apiSaveCall(payload)(dispatch).then((res) => {
            if(response) {

            }    
        })
    }
   ```
3. If you want an automatic way just do: it continue checking if the value has changed for loading

   ```
    const onSave = (): Promise<void> => {
    //wait for onchange api to complete and trigger save api call.
      let timer = window.setInterval(()=>{
        if(this.state.isLoading === false){
           window.clearInterval(timer)
         }
        apiSaveCall(payload)(dispatch).then((res) => {
            if(response) {

            }    
        })}, 100)
    }
   ```